# Is there a variable containing the domain name in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am doing come configuration refactoring of an nginx/1.14.1 server which acts as a reverse-proxy to PHP-FPM.

The way it's now configured, I'm able to do

```
# in a server {} section at a vhost there's
# set $base_domain domain.com;
# and then it includes another config file which has something like this: 
if ($php_logs_path = '') {
    set $php_logs_path /a/b/$base_domain/logs/$server_name.php_www_errors.log;
}
fastcgi_parma PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "error_log=$php_logs_path"
```

This works fine and the log file appears at the right path:

```
/a/b/domain.com/logs/some-sub-domain.domain.com.php_www_errors.log
```

However, I don't particularly like the fact I now need to go over hundred vhosts to set the `$base_domain` variable. I went over the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html), but I couldn't find a variable which gives only the `domain` segment without the sub-domain.

Is there an easy way to do this with a custom variable?

Comment: A proper solution would reference the Public Suffix List, but this is well beyond the capability of an nginx configuration file. It could conceivably be incorporated into some configuration management system's generator/template system, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using some global `map` directive like

```
map $server_name $base_domain {
    ~([^.]*)\.([^.]*)$    $1.$2;
}
```

`map` blocks are defined in `http` context so you can define it separately from your vhosts in the global nginx config.

**Update**

As OP noted, this solution wouldn't work with `.co.uk` domain. I thought of other examples writing this answer - for example, Australian `.com.au`, `.net.au`, Ukrainian `.com.ua`, `.in.ua` and many others. Well, since the national TLDs are always [two letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Country_code_top-level_domains), we can assume that any `.xx.xx` and `.xxx.xx` domain suffix is very likely some national two component TLD. Since the list of `map` block expressions checked from first to last, those domains could be catched with the following `map` block:

```
map $server_name $base_domain {
    "~([^.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})\.([a-z]{2})$"    $1.$2.$3;
    ~([^.]*)\.([^.]*)$                       $1.$2;
}
```

**Update 2**

Just figured out, there is no need for several capture groups in these regexes:

```
map $server_name $base_domain {
    "~([^.]*\.[a-z]{2,3}\.[a-z]{2})$"    $1;
    ~([^.]*\.[^.]*)$                     $1;
}
```

Comment: That's a great workaround! This won't work for `co.uk`, but I could fix that manually (the majority is domain.com/org/etc). In JS you could do `example.domain.co.uk'.match(/\.(\w*)/g).join('')` and it would return `.domain.co.uk` so you can just remove the first letter and you're done. But it looks like this doesn't work in nginx the same way. If you have ideas about this - feel free to update the answer. I'll mark it as accepted anyway since it solves my issue for the better part. Thanks! :)

Comment: @tftd Check the updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the updated version! :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just reuse `$server_name`? This variable is set to the *first* `server_name` defined in the `server` block. Just make sure the first defined name is the one you want (and it probably already is).

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work, because of the directory structure - `/a/b/domain.com/` contains all domains and subdomains for `domain.com`. In this case, `server_name` would make the path look like this: `/a/b/some-sub-domain.domain.com/logs/some-sub-domain.domain.com.php_www_errors.log` and it doesn't exist, because it's under `/a/b/domain.com/logs/some-subdomain.domain.com`.

Comment: @tftd In that case you're probably going to have to do what you're already doing.